# Sessions not saving on hosting

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5, hosting

Suddenly my sessions are not saving anymore in my project. 
I think it started after installing the laravel-localization package.

The strange thing is that when using the "php artisan serve" command, the sessions do work on my localhost.

Might this be a problem with my hosting (one.com)? It did work on my hosting but suddenly not...

```
use App;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Mail;


public function getLanding(Request $request) {
    $value = $request->session()->get('allowed');
    echo "session: " . $value;
    if( $value == "true" ) {
        echo "test true";
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
    else {
        echo "test false";
        return view(App::getLocale() . '.pages.landing');
    }

}

public function postLanding(Request $request) {

    if ( isset($_POST['buttonTrue']) ) {
        // enter website
        $request->session()->put('allowed', 'true');
        return redirect()->route('home');
    } else {
        // do not enter
        $request->session()->put('allowed', 'false');
        return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

The webpage always returns the "test false" echo.

Comment: you might want to check permissions on the session folder if you are using the (file system) in the config

Comment: The permissions are fine. I can actually see a lot of sessions in that folder. Everytime I visit the page, a new one is created.

Comment: Could you try to store the sessions in a [database](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#introduction) instead to identify the problem?